# What is Laura Barton's history?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, avengers-age-of-ultron

In Age of Ultron, Clint Barton reveals his wife to the Avengers when he takes them to his farm to recover off the grid.  None of them recognize her because Fury set things up so that no one would know that Clint had a family.  This would protect Clint's family from retribution, etc.

**But has Laura Barton been a character in other Marvel stories?**

For example, Romanov knew Laura Barton and her kids well, even though the other Avengers did not know that she existed?

Comment: See also: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/258574/was-laura-barton-ever-an-agent-of-s-h-i-e-l-d

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Laura Barton in the MCU

She hadn't been mentioned or acknowledged prior to the events of *Avengers: Age of Ultron* in the Marvel Cinematic Universe ([Earth-199999](http://marvel.wikia.com/Earth-199999)).

### Laura Barton in the Comics

Laura Barton does appear in the Ultimate Comics Universe ([Earth-1610](http://marvel.wikia.com/Earth-1610)), upon which the MCU is heavily based, as a matter of fact. From the [Marvel Wikia](http://marvel.wikia.com/Laura_Barton_(Earth-1610)):

> Despite his dangerous, globe-spanning profession, Clint Barton managed to build a more stable family life than most of his peers, residing for years with his girlfriend Laura. She later became his wife, with whom he had three children: Callum, Lewis and baby Nicole, named after her godfather, Nick Fury. Hawkeye habitually phoned his family before every mission to say good-bye, just in case he never returned; but he always returned.

This matches almost perfectly MCU's Laura Barton, except their children are named Cooper, Lila, and Nathaniel Pietro. Much like in the *Ultimate Universe*, the Bartons' younger child is named in honour of Clint's friends/colleagues: Nathaniel is the masculine form of Natasha (in honour of Natasha Romanoff, the Black Widow), and Pietro is the first name of Quicksilver (Pietro Maximoff), who

> was killed when he saved Hawkeye and a child from being struck by gunfire, during the climactic battle with Ultron in Sokovia.

Comment: Nathaniel Pietro... breaks my heart.

Answer (score 1):

> But has Laura Barton been a character in other Marvel stories?

In MCU, No.
Her appearance in "Age of Ultron" was her [first appearance](http://marvel-movies.wikia.com/wiki/Laura_Barton#Appearances.2FActresses).

In non-MCU, yes.

As of June 2015 a character with that name has only appeared in one other story.

see

- http://marvel.wikia.com/Laura_Barton_%28Earth-1610%29
- http://marvel.com/universe/Hawkeye_%28Ultimate%29

Specially in [Ultimate Comics (aka Earth-1610)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_Marvel) in

- [Ultimates 2 #1   2005, February](http://marvel.wikia.com/Ultimates_2_Vol_1_1)
- [Ultimates 2 #4   2005, May](http://marvel.wikia.com/Ultimates_2_Vol_1_4)
- [Ultimates 2 #7   2005, September](http://marvel.wikia.com/Ultimates_2_Vol_1_7)

Comment: This would be a way better answer if it included a summary of Laura Barton and anything that was particularly notable, instead of just a link.

Comment: Ellesedil, I respectfully disagree. It was a very simple question. A summary was not asked for. Adding unasked-for detail to any question dilutes the actual answer and lowers overall quality. But this is a topic for meta really.

Comment: CodeMed, fair comment as regards the links. I have added that data to my answer. If you want a summary I would encourage you to ask a separate question taking time to explain what you need from a summary.

Comment: You can't say "No" and just throw a bunch of links. That's [not how this site works](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Alfredo Hernández, are you referring to the current or original version of the answer? I accept the first version was very poor quality.

Comment: The old one. Any way, it's always encouraged not to only provide links, but also quote relevant excerpts from them, as the websites could be deleted or changed.

Comment: Also: [**Bring the content here**](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/602/21267).