# Was Laura Barton ever an Agent of S.H.I.E.L.D.?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, hawkeye-2021

In *Hawkeye* (2021),

> a vintage Rolex is auctioned off on the black market, stolen from the Avengers compound.

However, Hawkeye and

> Kate Bishop are able to steal it back from Maya's apartment.

Then, in the finale (1x6),

> Barton gives the watch to Laura Barton, who turns it over, revealing the S.H.I.E.L.D. logo.

This raised the question: **was Laura Barton ever an Agent of S.H.I.E.L.D.?** It would make sense, seeing as she somehow met Clint, although that's not proof enough.

Comment: I think it answered that question, rather than raising it.

Comment: Do we have any mention or confirmation in MCU canon *other* than the watch? No is a perfectly acceptable answer

Comment: I’ve downvoted this question. The implication is clearly that she worked for SHIELD and it was hinted at in a previous episode.

Comment: Hinted at in a previous episode? How so?

Comment: @PeterNielsen S1E4, “Partners, Right?” Clint says the watch belonged to someone he used to work with who has been “out of the game for a long time.” He adds that this mysterious former colleague’s identity is still attached to the watch, so retrieving it is imperative to keeping them safe.

Comment: @PeterNielsen - additionally, in episode 3 (or 4?) she spoke Russian to Clint and was shown to be very aware of all of his past (beyond just being Hawkeye). It seemed pretty clear to this viewer that they were laying the groundwork to show that she was more than just a 'happy homemaker' with no connection to the larger 'superhero' world beyond being married to one.

Comment: @NKCampbell wasn’t she speaking German? That’s the scene I was referring to with the hinting at previously as well.

Comment: maybe @TheLethalCarrot - I thought it was Russian. Either way, it was entirely unexpected coming from what we'd previously been shown of the character

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes Laura Barton used to work for SHIELD and as the watch is hers that would make her Agent 19. The watch is hers and it has the SHIELD logo on the back of it. On top of that Clint remarks it belonged to someone he used to work with.

> **Kate:** Okay, what am I lookin' for?
>
> **Clint:** A watch, vintage Rolex. Belongs to someone I used to work with.
>
> **Kate:** Is that the whole story, Clint?
>
> **Clint:** They've been out of the game a long time, but their identity is still attached to that watch.
>
> **Kate:** Hmm. And if the Tracksuits find out about it?
>
> **Clint:** It would blow their cover. Goodbye, friend.
>
> <sub>*Hawkeye*, Season 1 Episode 4, “Partners, Am I Right?”</sub>

> **Clint:** I want you to take better care of your stuff.
>
> <sub>*Hawkeye*, Season 1 Episode 6, “The Boss”</sub>

Rhys Thomas also confirms that Laura is Agent 19 in the below interview:

> “That's what's exciting about the Marvel Cinematic Universe,” Rhys Thomas, the finale episode’s director tells Marvel.com. “It's Marvel, and the comics are so deep. It's a universe. What I love is that these ideas could get introduced as we were sort of prepping the show.”
>
> Laura Barton, played by Linda Cardellini, has been a part of the MCU since Marvel Studios’ Avengers: Age of Ultron, where she was introduced as Clint’s off-the-grid wife. Living deep in the middle of nowhere on a secluded farm, she’s been raising the Barton kids while Clint’s away saving the world. But, turns out, that her history with Clint runs deeper than viewers initially realize.
>
> “We've seen her over these years as his wife, and there was obviously a desire [to expand her backstory],” Thomas continues. “We should know more about her. There's more to her than just staying at home with the kids. It was a fun little thing to tease out over the season and again a nice little payoff that hopefully promises more of a character planted at the end.”
>
> <sub>[Marvel.com, ‘Hawkeye’: Laura Barton’s Reveal and Keeping Christmas Alive at the Farm House](https://www.marvel.com/articles/tv-shows/hawkeye-laura-barton-agent-19-christmas)</sub>

Comment: Maybe S.H.I.E.L.D. gives out numbered watches to agents spouses?

Comment: @SillybutTrue Introducing... ***LIFE PARTNER 19***

Comment: Rhys Thomas was actually talking about her exciting history with _couponing._

Answer (score 4):

Elsewhere in the MCU, the nearest we have to supporting evidence is Tony's keen sense of intuition about SHIELD agents in *Age of Ultron*:

> CLINT: Company, sorry I didn't call ahead.
> LAURA: Hey.
> TONY: This is an agent of some kind.

(This is the same Tony who thought Natasha Romanov was just a personal assistant who happened to be really good at Krav Maga back in *Iron Man 2*, but maybe that was the palladium poisoning.)

If we zoom over to the comics, Clint was married to [Bobbi Morse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mockingbird_(Marvel_Comics)), who was also known as both Mockingbird, and **Agent 19** of SHIELD.

As the watch we see in *Hawkeye* also has the number 19 on the back, this seems like a clear implication that in the MCU Laura Barton was an agent of SHIELD. (Maybe the 19th? It's not clear how the numbering works.)

Previously in the show, Clint told Kate that the watch belonged to "a friend" he used to work with, who'd been out of the game for a long time, and that the watch could compromise their identity and put them at risk. Although Laura is more than his friend, this fits fine with what little we already know about her, and her remark to Clint about how careful "they'd" been.

(In *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.*, which may or may not be canon for the MCU, a character named Bobbi Morse was played by Adrianne Palicki, but [was (I believe) never referred to as Agent 19](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/83746/440), and had no connection to Hawkeye.)

Answer (score -1):

### Yes.

Based on the circumstantial evidence we see in *Hawkeye (2021)*, your assertion is a reasonable conclusion at this time, as any that can be surmised from the currently available information.

We are likely to find out more in Phase 4, or even Phase 5 execution that might even include a West Coast Avengers team or grouping or flashback stories that see “Mockingbird” in uniform.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question asked, other than referring back to the evidence already cited in the question.

Comment: True but lacking a smoking gun which doesn’t yet exist as of 12/23/21 Marvel playing coy about what everyone already knows is all we have to go on right now.

Comment: Well, we have interviews and cast and crew commentary

Comment: But Lethalcarrot covers about the most exhaustive examples of that type of BTS commentary on the life of Hawkeye’s wife, and even _that_ doesn’t explicitly confirm anything. We all know it, but no one’s stated it.